# Material Opacity in viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

I'd like to do motion graphics type work in blender and it would be really helpful if I could see the results of keyframing material opacity to cut items in and out of view.

Blender internal is sufficient, using shadeless materials.  I could have swore there used to be something in view options.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 24):

Object panel > Display > Transparency Checkbox.

This works for Blender Internal but not Cycles.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I discovered why ! didn't find it, this doesn't work for text objects only meshes.  too bad:(

Comment: You can convert text to a mesh with alt + C then selecting mesh from curve.

Comment: great solution:)

Comment: @comeinandburn - You may want to check out this [BA thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?295010-Blender-text-conversion-improvements-wishlist) about suggesting improvements for the text system.

Comment: will do.  I didn't know this thread existed. thanks!

Comment: @comeinandburn if your question has been answered satisfactorily, you could consider [accepting an answer.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @RayMairlot I just wanted to let you know that this now does work in Cycles in the 3D Viewport. Thanks again!

Comment: @ShadyPuck - How to achive transparency in Cycles 3D Viewport?

Comment: This for me only works when selecting GLSL in the Viewport's Shading options. Doesnàt work with Multitexture.

Comment: I don't see this option in Blender 2.91.

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it in Blender 2.8 is to adjust the Alpha value of the diffuse color of the material:

> Material > Viewport Display > Color > Alpha --> to a value between 0--1

[image]

[reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbz0Pfe8qVU)

Answer (score 5):

For cycles use the alpha box under Viewport in the material menu. When set to zero it will make the transparency work in the viewport in material view mode.

The transparency box in display pannel in the object menu will make the object itself have transparency when un selected.

Answer (score 5):

In the latest Blender (2.90) along with selecting an *alpha* for the material, I also needed to select *Blend Mode* as *Alpha Blend* from the settings at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's insane how some basic capabilities are buried within submenus of submenus... Imagine whether it's be as simple as just assigning the alpha property of the material it'self.

Comment: @Reahreic I second that :)

Answer (score 0):

My Blender version v2.81.16 (menu items may differ in other versions) thank all, very helped.

[image]

[image]