# How do I make a transparent material display in the 3D view?

Tags: materials, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

How do I make a transparent material always display?
I have turned the transparency on but its clearly not showing in the 3D view.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cycles/Eevee and 2.8+ you need to set the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Blend* in the Material Settings:

[image]

Then set the viewport render level to Material or Rendered.

---

In older versions of blender:

Enable *Transparency* in *Properties > Object > Display*:

[image]

Comment: I never new about that one, nice work!!!!.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this topic but things have changed.
Where the transparency option on blender 2.92?

Comment: @Carlos No need to apologize! In 2.92 it's in the material settings, try this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197024/599

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your view mode to either *Rendered* or *Texture*.
[image]

If you set it to textured, you will need to change your Shading to GLSL in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>).

[image]