# Show plane texture while in weight paint mode

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, weight-painting

Like you can see on the second image, I painted some areas brown. I made a particle system with grass an tree items and I want to use weight paint to spread them over the model. I only don't want them on the brown area but when I switch to weight paint than do the textures disappear.

**I am using the blender render engine and my blender version is 2.74**

My question: **how can I still see the textures while in weight paint**

[image]

Comment: One way could be to enter Edit mode whille GLSL shading enabled so to see the texture, select vertices / faces where brown texture is drawn (it can be roughly selection though) and assign these vertices to Vertex Group (probably adding some weight to them).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use an image texture as a guide for weight painting?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/how-can-i-use-an-image-texture-as-a-guide-for-weight-painting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the 3d view shading type to ***Rendered***, select the area you want to paint on with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, change the mode to *Weight Paint* and...paint!
[image]

Comment: It is not ideal but it works. One other question. How do I close the selected window?

Comment: Really good question @Vinc199789, which may demand a separate enquiry because I DON'T KNOW! It's easy to do it in camera view, but in ortographic view it's not that easy. I usually select just a very little portion with Ctrl+B to make the border window smaller, but I don't know how to get rid of it (make it completelly invisible) :(.

Comment: found the answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6341/how-do-i-clear-the-render-border    ctrl + alt + B

Comment: @Vinc199789 thanks! Mystery has been solved! :D

Answer (score 1):

Just go to **Show overlays option** on right top corner [image]

and then turn down the opacity while in weight paint mode [image] [image]