# Texture Painting Transparent

Tags: transparency

I have a problem with texture painting in Blender. 
I can't seem to get the transparency to show up in the viewport.

I have made the material transparent. Painted the texture. 
But it just appears white like here.
[image]

But I'd like for it to actually be transparent in the viewport.
GLSL is active too, btw.

Comment: I think the way to go is to turn on Transparency in material settings, enable [transparency in display properties](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/material-opacity-in-viewport) to see that this object actually is transparent if rendered (this works only for BI).

Answer (score 5):

You can do that in GLSL Textured Viewport Shading

First open material tab, enable Transparency and set Alpha to 0

[image]

Then open Texture tab, select the texture you are painting on and in Influence section enable **Alpha**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In cyles you need to create a material that uses the alpha channel to control the transparency.

[image]

Then Set the display to rendered view ( <kbd>Shift</kbd>
 <kbd>Z</kbd>)

[image: ]]

Answer (score -1):

Transparency won't show on viewport when using Blender Cycles (as far as I know, but don't quote me on that), you have to be using Blender Render. On my scene this happened by accident but it might help you, this object doesn't have any materials or textures, I just have the image selected on the UV/Image Editor and as you can see the transparency is showing on viewport. So you can do this while you work on it and then later when you want to render it just add the materials and textures.

[image: proof]

Comment: I'm not quite sure this answers the question, and if it does, it is not very clear. Would you revise your answer to make it more clear?

Comment: Use Blender Render and set the texture on UV/Image Editor instead of as a texture on material.

Comment: @Eirikra In cycles you need to create a transparent shader and control the transparency with the alpha channel of the texture. see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39287/1853