# How to render transparent textures in blender render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I've managed to make the background of the image transparent, but I can't work out how to render the transparent textures on the leaves as transparent and not opaque. How do you do this?

[image]

here's a link to the blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/?1iou4i1ansu2a6s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Texture Painting Transparent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33214/texture-painting-transparent)

Comment: please to share files use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, (free permanent, integrated) then paste the provided link editing the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Material Tab, go to Transparency Section, activate leaves' Material transparency, set it's transparency mode to "Z Transparency" and then set the Alpha value to 0.

On Texture Tab, go to Influence Section, tick Alpha and set it's value to 1. Don't forget to tick Use Alpha on Image Section.

[image: Screenshot for Transparency]

If you use an opaque image with transparency mask image, you can make the transparency mask to overlay the opaque image one using Texture Index and do things above (But, I don't guarantee it will always work).

if material still black in render mode, On Material Tab go to Shadow section tick Receive Trasparent e don't tick Cast.

Comment: Seems to be already answered this way [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33223/15265).