# Blender alpha/transparent texture only works when selected

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a transparent bubble texture that I got from google and I placed it on a part. I set the alpha to 0, made sure my shading setting is on GLNL like a youtube video instructed me to, but I only get my desired result when its being selected. If anyone knows how to fix this please help as soon as possible.[image]

[image]

[image]

The first picture is my desired result which is when its selected, the second picture is the result I get, and third picture is the texture I used.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1056/26640

Answer (score 2):

select your object then Go to the object panel in the properties and check Transparency in Display tab for all object you want to see transparent. make sure that you have the correct object selected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked perfectly, Have a nice day!

Comment: @Mariah welcome and don't forgot to select my answer :D